# Testing difference of medians and stochastic ordering using paired samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, paired-data, group-differences, two-sample

I have paired samples from skewed distributions with unequal variance (before and after treatment), and would like to test for

- difference of means
- difference of medians
- stochastic ordering of treated vs untreated

and get confidence intervals if possible. I currently have small samples (n=12 in each group) but might get larger samples if necessary.

I think I know how to proceed for the difference of means: I can use a paired test, for example Chen's t-test. Indeed for the populations, the difference of means can be calculated using an arbitrary pairing and taking the mean of the differences. So an estimator of the mean difference for a particular pairing (the one I have) is also an estimator of the difference of means.

But what about the difference of medians, and stochastic ordering? The questions I must answer are specifically about differences between the groups (treated vs untreated), not about the effect on individuals.

For now all I can think of is to split randomly the individuals in halves A and B, and use two sample (unpaired) tests on half A before treatment vs half B after treatment. Is there a better way?